# Xamarin forms: The equivalent of .Finish()

Tags: mobile, xamarin, cross-platform

I have a Xamarin Forms application which very well on all three platforms. The app has a login screen and other pages that are available one a user has successfully logged in. My question is: In Xamarin Forms; is there a way to have the equivalent of the Finish method that Xamrin for Android provides to remove the login page from the navigation stack? If a user keeps pressing the back button they eventually get back to the login screen which is undesirable. I have tried using Navigation.PopAsync () but seem not to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Navigation.PopAsync` and `Navigation.RemovePage` should definitely work.

BUT if your page is also a `MainPage` you can't remove it. You could change it to another page using this code:

```net
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyContentPage());
```

Comment: If the information was useful, please mark it as a correct answer. Thanks.