# how to prevent back button to login page after user logs in ( Xamarin Forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

i have a log in page where user enters username and password and then the user is redirected to his account page, but when i press the back button it takes me back to the log in page. How do i prevent that from happening.
Code Snippet:

```cs
public Login ()
{
    if (App.IsUserLoggedIn == false)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    else
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new LoginIndexPage()));
    }
}

private async void LoginButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var user = new Xcore.Users.csUser
    {
        RefNo = referansnoEntry.Text,
        Username = usernameEntry.Text,
        Password = passwordEntry.Text
    };
    var isValid = IsCorrectLogin(user);
    if (isValid)
    {
        App.IsUserLoggedIn = true;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new LoginIndexPage()));
    }
    else
    {
        showError.Text = "*Hatalı giriş";
        passwordEntry.Text = string.Empty;
        usernameEntry.Text = string.Empty;
        referansnoEntry.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
private bool IsCorrectLogin(Xcore.Users.csUser user)
{
    return user.RefNo == Xcore.Users.RegInfo.RefNo 
        && user.Username == Xcore.Users.RegInfo.Username 
        && user.Password == Xcore.Users.RegInfo.Password;
}


public LoginIndexPage()
{
    if (App.IsUserLoggedIn == true)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    else
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new Login()));
    }
}
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    showuserName.Text = Xcore.Users.RegInfo.Username;
}
```

When i login, its going on LoginIndexPage.

Comment: Check out this answear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035997/xamarin-forms-the-equivalent-of-finish

Answer (score 5):

Similar to what App Pack mentioned, you should not have LoginPage in the navigation stack. Instead of trying to remove it, just set the *next* page to the root page.

Instead of *pushing* the next page onto the stack, set it :

`Application.Current.MainPage = <your next page>`

Also, I wouldn't navigate to a page in the constructor of a page. That's not really a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Usually in this situation I would remove the login page from the Navigation Stack.

I believe there is a method on Navigation such as Navigation.RemovePage(Page page) as you are navigating away from the login page. That way your back-stack and functionality stays in place but will not go back to the login page as it has been removed from the stack.

What you must remember however, is that if the login was the root page, there does need to still be a page in the stack when you call pop().

Answer (score 1):

try use this code in your LoginIndexPage.

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        return true; // true prevent navigation back and false to allow

    }
```

Comment: Yes i can do it. But its not a good solution for that. I must use a session variable. But how can i use ?